# Selenium webdriver gives error when trying to access 2nd button using xpath with a variable as index in python

Tags: python-3.x

The below code is not working. It gives the following error:

> NoSuchElementException

```
a=2
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='something'])[a]") 
btn.click()
```

When I give

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='check-availability'])[2]") 
btn.click()
```

It works. It clicks the second button. But if I replace 2 with a variable its giving the error noted above.

Can somebody help with the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below,

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("(//*[@id='check-availability'])[{0}]").format(int(a)))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. It worked also without using int(a) inside format(just by giving format(a) it worked). What is the difference in the way the value is taken in both the usages(using format and without using format)?

Comment: without format, you are basically not saying to take a value that's assigned to "a", since it's within the quotes